# Retrieving information from wiki table using XPath in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve the name of the country out of the capital city wiki page, specifically from the main information table of the city, using xpath.

For example I want to retrieve "Spain" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona

[xml format for Barcelona table country row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAXFu.png)

[Barcelona information table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChjWO.png)

URL is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona

```
import requests
import lxml.html

res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)
country = doc.xpath("//table[@class='infobox geography vcard']//tr[@class = 'mergedtoprow']//th[contains(text(), 'Country')]/td//a//text()")
```

Which didn't get any results

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tr` contains the `th` and the `td` as siblings so move the `th` check into a predicate:

```
//table[@class='infobox geography vcard']//tr[@class = 'mergedtoprow'][th = 'Country']/td//a//text()
```

When I run

```
import requests
import lxml.html

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona'

res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)

country = doc.xpath("//table[@class='infobox geography vcard']//tr[@class = 'mergedtoprow'][th = 'Country']/td//a//text()")

print(country)
```

It outputs `['Spain']`.

As there are some entries without a link I think it is easier to use `xpath("string(//table[@class='infobox geography vcard']//tr[@class = 'mergedtoprow'][th = 'Country']/td)")`.

Comment: thanks but still it doesn't work for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona 
it does work for other cities like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin 
can't understand why

Comment: @Jackson, can you show us the Python code you use? Please edit the question and insert it there.

Comment: @Jackson, I have tried your Python code, I get the output `['Spain']` when printing the `country` variable. So which result or error exactly do you get when you say "still it doesn't work"?

Comment: sorry my bad you right I probably missed a character or something when I checked it. But for some reason it doesn't catch it for all cases like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel
I'm at a loss here as to why it's happening, thank you

Comment: That entry for Basel doesn't link to the country so you might rather want `xpath("string(//table[@class='infobox geography vcard']//tr[@class = 'mergedtoprow'][th = 'Country']/td)")`. That will give you a string directly in the Python variable `country`, not a list with a string.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter form :

```
normalize-space(//th[@scope][.="Country"]/following-sibling::td)
```

Output : `Spain`

Comment: So it did find "Spain" but for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel it didn't find "Switzerland"

Comment: OK.  You already have the solution, but I've edited the answer.